# POS terminal Application Development - SDK, programming languages, patterns, IDEs

Tags: c++, c, gcc, sdk, terminal-emulator

In regards to POS (Point of Sale) Terminal Application Development, I would like to know, at least, one of these info (any experience and link to related websites would be appreciated as well):

1. most common SDK for such terminals (probably proprietary ones)
2. most common languages, compilers and DB that is used (maybe C/C++, GCC, SQLite?)
3. best design patterns to use
4. most common IDE
5. Testing framework

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I want just share my experience about POS development.

> 1.most common SDK for such terminals (probably proprietary ones)

First, choose your device, for example you can write an application for Castles/VEGA7000. Go to the related [site](http://www.castech.com.tw/) and download SDKs. There is a SDK under Cygwin for Castles/VEGA7000.

> 2.most common languages, compilers and DB that is used (maybe C/C++, GCC, SQLite?)

For example, Castles/VEGA7000 supports standard C.

> 3.best design patterns to use

I don't remember any special case which needs a specific design pattern. Think like normal PC programs.

> 4.most common IDE

The mentioned SDK has a plugin for Netbeans.

> 5.Testing framework

I can not help any more in this case!

If it helps, I can show you a Hello-World sample of Castles/VEGA7000:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctosapi.h>
#include <ctos_newlib_startup.h>

int main()
{
    BYTE key;

    sysheap_setup ( 256 * 1024 );

    CTOS_LCDTClearDisplay();    
    CTOS_LCDTPrint("Hello World!"); 
    CTOS_KBDGet(&key);  

    return 1;
}
```

After compile, It generates a binary file named `xyz.s19` then you should make a CAP file and write it on the device. The SDK has a tool for it.

[image]

Comment: Really thank you for this great answer. I want to develop for this POS also (Castless\VEGA 7000). But I couldn't find any SDK or Plugin or even Specification for it in its website (I think they remove it from the website). Can you refer me to somewhere else that I can find this kind of info and tools?

Comment: @deepmax can you help me, now the castles website don't support vega7000 and i should to program for this device, i need user manual and skd

Comment: @masoud does castless support multithreading ?